# Multi-input gradients calculation on keras with K.function

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, keras, backpropagation

#### This model.input is a four head placeholder with size (3, 227, 227)

```
input_imgs = model.input
loss = K.max(layer_dict[layer_name].output[p[0]])
```

#### compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, input_imgs)[0]
```

#### this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture

```
iterate = K.function(input_imgs, [grads])
```

I want to compute gradients for a siamese NN with fout head inputs, but when I apply the above K function I get a tensor of gradient with shape `(1, 3, 227, 227)`, when what I want is `(4, 3, 227, 227)`.

What can I do to get the correct gradients?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to generate saliency maps.

Check whats the shape of input_imgs tensor. Thats what determines the shape your gradient. My guess will be `input_imgs` is a list of tensors and in the `grads = K.gradients(loss, input_imgs)[0]` since you are indexing to `0` you are dropping all other gradients in the list. So probably this will fix your issue:

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, input_imgs)
iterate = K.function(input_imgs, grads)
```

Now when you use `iterate` it will give you a list of 4 each of shape `(1, 3, 227, 227)`

Comment: When i do it i got Can 'not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.'

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. Which line are you getting the error. But this problem should be easily fixable.